# Docker can't find script living in home dir

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

COPY keep-alive.sh $HOME/keep-alive.sh

CMD ["$HOME/keep-alive.sh"]
```

Yes I know its really useless but I am learning.

When I run this:

```
$ docker run -d --name linux-worker myorg/linux-worker
71cfc9ff7072688d1758f2ac98a8293ed2bcf77bf68f980da20237c9961aca6c
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"$HOME/keep-alive.sh\": stat $HOME/keep-alive.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

All I want the container to do is start up and run `$HOME/keep-alive.sh`. **Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?**

Comment: $HOME what is the value?

Comment: That could very well be the root (no pun intended!) of my confusion. I thought `$HOME` would be the homedir of the root user, no?

Comment: you can just do a "echo $HOME" to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$HOME` environment variable will not be set when running the `COPY` instruction in your Dockerfile so your script was likely placed at `/keep-alive.sh` instead of `/root/keep-alive.sh` where your `CMD` instruction expects it to be.

Check the logs of your build and you'll likely see that line executed like:

```
=> [3/3] COPY keep-alive.sh /keep-alive.sh
```

instead of:

```
=> [3/3] COPY keep-alive.sh /root/keep-alive.sh
```

To fix this, you can explicitly set an environment variable to use in this command:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

ENV DIR /root

COPY keep-alive.sh $DIR/keep-alive.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "$DIR/keep-alive.sh"]
```

Another change that had to be made was to specify that you want the script to be run in a shell so it will expand environment variables. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40454758/4676641) for more details about this issue.

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use environment variables at all, you could change that line to this if you know the script's path:

```
CMD [ "/root/keep-alive.sh" ]
```