# Shell script failing on mkdir in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell

Have a Shell script as follows

```
ENV HOME=/home
RUN mkdir $HOME
```

Above script is in a Docker file and getting exception as follows
[91mmkdir: missing operand
Try `'mkdir --help'` for more information.
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454470/how-can-i-use-a-variable-inside-a-dockerfile-cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried with a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM scratch
ENV HOME=/home
RUN mkdir $HOME
```

and got that:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 ---> 
Step 2/3 : ENV HOME=/home
 ---> Running in e9d03ee00aa7
Removing intermediate container e9d03ee00aa7
 ---> 16f6e2ba2f09
Step 3/3 : RUN mkdir $HOME
 ---> Running in 6847b9b34717
failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
$
```

Then I edited the file to look like this:

```
FROM mariadb
ENV HOME=/home
RUN mkdir $HOME
```

and got that:

```
$ docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM mariadb
 ---> ea81af801379
Step 2/3 : ENV HOME=/home
 ---> Running in 7d903215da74
Removing intermediate container 7d903215da74
 ---> 77276b970083
Step 3/3 : RUN mkdir $HOME
 ---> Running in f120f966144f
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home': File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir $HOME' returned a non-zero code: 1
$
```

From the error message I can see the $HOME variable would not have been an issue. It should have worked on your side as well.