# Docker - How to interpolate

Tags: docker

I have the below `Dockerfile` where I need to interpolate the filename to be run.

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7-alpine

# Use the python image as the base image
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

# set environment to run
ENV ENVIRONMENT={ENVIRONMENT:-"prod"}

# Copy the python files
COPY requirements.txt /app/
COPY prod.py dev.py requirements.txt /app/

# Set the working directory 
WORKDIR /app

# Install the dependencies 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Set the command to run the python file when the container is started
CMD ["python", "${ENVIRONMENT}.py"]
```

But when I build the image and run it, I get the following error:

> python: can't open file '${ENVIRONMENT}.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Why this is not interpolated correctly? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You may be missing the declaration of the environment variable `ENVIRONMENT` during the build

Comment: I would advise you to use a docker-compose file which selects the command to be executed by the container based on the environment variable instead ..

Comment: You could use the shell form without JSON-array syntax `CMD ./$ENVIRONMENT.py`, but it might be easier to just override the entire command when you run the image `docker run your-image ./dev.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to have something like a `run.py` which reads the `$ENVIRONMENT` variable and then loads the correct file. Or, depending on how far `dev.py` and `prod.py` diverge, they could even be one file after all.

Comment: So I can't use string interpolation here?

Comment: I don’t think you can use the extrapolation syntax, but I don’t have a source to support that. There are apparently some ways to achieve what you want by decomposition, or by wrapping into another shell, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454470/how-can-i-use-a-variable-inside-a-dockerfile-cmd