# Use Jenkins variable in Dockerfile command

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, environment-variables, nestjs

I am new to Docker and Jenkins. I have to build and deploy Nest Js app in jenkins. When I run the Jenkins job I have to select the 'DEPLOY_PROFILE' which is equals to 'dev' and 'qa' as follows.

[image]

This is my Dockerfile,

```
    FROM node:16-alpine
    WORKDIR /app
    ADD package.json /app/package.json
    RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
    RUN npm install
    ADD . /app
    EXPOSE 3000
    CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I need to pass the 'DEPLOY_PROFILE' variable which is equals to 'dev' or 'qa' to the Dockerfile. Then final docker command should be look like `npm run start:dev` or `npm run start:qa`

I have tried using

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "start", `:${DEPLOY_PROFILE}`]
```

and

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "start", `:${env.DEPLOY_PROFILE}`]
```

But nothing gave me the luck. Any help may highly appreciated!

Comment: You can provide a replacement command when you run the container.  If the only thing this is used for is to set the default `CMD`, can you default it to `npm run start` but then explicitly `docker run your-image npm run start:qa` if you need to?  Also see [How can I use a variable inside a Dockerfile CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454470/how-can-i-use-a-variable-inside-a-dockerfile-cmd)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an environment variable for that. In your dockerfile, declare an argument (passed into docker build) and an environment variable like this:

```
ARG DEPLOY_PROFILE
ENV PROFILE=${deploy_profile}
```

Then use the environment variable like this:

```
CMD npm run start $PROFILE
```

Then call buildah (or whatever you are using) like this:

```
 buildah bud --format=docker --build-arg deploy_profile="$DEPLOY_PROFILE"
```

Comment: The `CMD` must be in bare-string form; the JSON-array syntax does not expand environment variables.